# API Controller unable to read Json from POST body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

### Background

I'm sending JSON in my body to my API controller but keep getting the following error.

> {"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path
>   '', line 1, position 1."]}

**My HTTP request**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequest httpRequest;
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = null;
httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", HostnameTb.Text, null);

var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "APIKey", APIKeyTb.Text }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
StringContent content = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
httpResponse = client.PostAsync(HostnameTb.Text, content).Result;

var responseString = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**My Controller looks like this.**

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] string value)
{
  //Never gets here.
}
```

**The Json in the body.**

> {"APIKey":"1283f0f8..."}

### Question

I would prefer to use the .Net Core `[From Body]` functionality, rather than getting the content manually.

I would expect the JSON string to be available in the string `Value` parameter.

What am I missing?

Comment: try renaming the parameter to match the json property name?

Comment: Also, confirm the json string is valid

Comment: @RuiJarimba Your first suggestion didn't work, and I have validated the Json, it's find. The example I posted is the Json, with the value changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ASP.NET Core tries to deserialize `{"APIKey":"1283f0f8..."}` from JSON into a `string` value, and fails, because it expects the input to be a valid JSON string.

In other words, if your body was `"{\"APIKey\":\"1283f0f8...\"}"` you would have the JSON string in the input variable as you expect.

In order to get the `APIKey` value without changing the HTTP request, create an input type:

```
public class Input
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

and use that as the input of your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] Input input)
{
    var apiKey = input.ApiKey;
    // etc
}
```

Alternatively, change your HTTP request to send a `string`:

```
// ...
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
// ...
```

Note the use of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` instead of `ToString()`; `"foo".ToString()` is still just `"foo"`, while you want `"\"foo\""`.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how this works. `[FromBody]` invokes a serializer to deserialize the request body. Then, the modelbinder attempts to bind that to the param. Here, it cannot do that because you're binding to a string, and the request body is a dictionary. Essentially what's happening under the hood (pseudo-code) is:

```
value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(dictionaryAsJson);
```

You're getting a deserialization error from JSON.NET because it can't parse the JSON into a string.

If you want the value as a string, then you should post is as something like `text/plain` instead of `application/json`. Otherwise, you'll need to bind to a type that actually represents the JSON object coming in, which would be a `Dictionary<string, string>` here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with ASP.NET Core 3.1. I was POSTing a JSON to my API controller that looked like:

```
public JsonResult Save([FromBody]MainDetails obj){ ... }
```

The problem in my case was that a property `ChildDetails.StartDate` of my `MainDetails` object was of type `DateTime`, and I was sending a `null` value in JSON. This was causing the deserialization to fail at the controller. I changed the property type to `DateTime?` from `DateTime` to make it work.

Basically, one needs to check and ensure that the JSON that you POST is valid for the target object to which you are deserializing it. If you have non-nullable properties for which the value sent in JSON is `null`, then your deserialization will fail (without telling you why).
Hope this helps.